# Issue with aligning back arrow with dropdown

Tags: html, css

Having issues with spacing a back arrow next to a dropdown. The issue is that it is centering the arrow as if the dropdown is active. I want it on the left of the dropdown not aligned how it is.

I included a jsfiddle show the display.

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
    <a href="index.html"><div class="back-arrow-left" ></div></a>
 </td>
 <td>
 <dropdown>
    <input id="toggle2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="toggle2" class="animate">Portfolio<i class="fa fa-list float-right"></i></label>
    <ul class="animate">
       <li class="animate">Websites</li>
       <li class="animate">Computer Animations</li>
       <li class="animate">C/C++ Programs</li>
    </ul>
 </dropdown>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.back-arrow-left {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 30px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
border-right:30px solid gray;
vertical-align: top;
}

.back-arrow-left:hover {
border-right:30px solid #1ABC9C;
}

#portfolio{
width: 400px;
float: right;
}

*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .float-right{
 float: right;
   }
   .fa{
    font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 22px !important;
    }
    dropdown{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0px 50px;
    }
    dropdown label, dropdown ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ECF0F1;
    padding: 15px 20px;
     }
   dropdown label:hover, dropdown ul li:hover{
   background: #1ABC9C;
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;}

   dropdown label{
   color: #1ABC9C;
   border-left: 4px solid #1ABC9C;
   border-radius: 0 5px 0 0; 
  position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
}
  dropdown input{
  display: none;
}
dropdown input ~ ul{
position: relative;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 top: -20px;
 z-index: 1;
}
dropdown input:checked + label{
 background: #1ABC9C;
 color: white;
 }

dropdown input:checked ~ ul{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 top: 0;
 }
  $colors: #E74C3C, #0072B5, #2C3E50;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
 dropdown ul li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
  border-left: 4px solid nth($colors, $i);
  .fa{
    color: nth($colors, $i);
  }
  &:hover {
    background: nth($colors, $i);
    color: white;
    .fa{
    color: white; 
    }
  }
  }
 }

.animate{
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
-moz-transition: all .3s;
-ms-transition: all .3s;
-ms-transition: all .3s;
transition: all .3s;  
backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Firefox */
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e1nuabgs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are using the table? This is not HTML 5 compliant, and could cause issues later on.

In fact, its the table that is causing your problem. You have the table surrounding the data which should orientate it into the order you want, but you are already using the css to align it with out the table!

If you take out the table and add one line to your css it work perfectly.

```
.back-arrow-left {
       float: left;
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-top: 30px solid transparent;
       border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
       border-right:30px solid gray;
       vertical-align: top;
}

<div id="portfolio">
    <a href="index.html"><div class="back-arrow-left" ></div></a>
    <dropdown>
      <input id="toggle2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="toggle2" class="animate">Portfolio<i class="fa fa-list float-right"></i></label>
         <ul class="animate">
           <li class="animate">Websites</li>
           <li class="animate">Computer Animations</li>
         <li class="animate">C/C++ Programs</li>
      </ul>
   </dropdown>
 </div>
```

[I've updated your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1nuabgs/5/)

Comment: I originally tried a div and came up with an error so I was just trying different things to get it to work and made a table. It wasn't clean code that I submitted here. Thanks though this worked fine.

Comment: Fair enough. :) If it happens again, just watch that the floats are in the right place and your divs widths don't overlap. You had it! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can give the table-data holding your back arrow a class and change the vertical alignment of to top.

```
.arrow_box{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1nuabgs/2/)